# Why should we bypass DataSet when updating DB?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

1)

a) Why is it preferable to bypass DataSet when updating, deleting or inserting records ( I realize using DataSet takes more CPU time and memory, but are there any other reasons besides that?! )?

b) Are direct updates faster than batch updates? Why?

c)  Why do Web services represent only real web application scenario in which it would make sense to perform batch updating through a DataSet?

2) We can use UpdateCommand to insert,delete or update rows in a database, so what is  the point of DataAdapter having InsertCommand,UpdateCommand and DeleteCommand  objects?
Why not just have one Command object instead of three ( or even four, since UpdateCommand could also be used for SELECT statements )?

thank you

Comment: I would have broken this into more than one question.

Answer (score 0):

1) I disagree with the whole assumptions made for the question. Also note that b) is plain wrong.

2) because you want different queries to be executed for the different actions, and when you have a dataset loaded with changes you just want to do a simple call that will do all the insert,delete and udpates.